# Typescript React React-Router V4 not routing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

My code is compiling and running, but just not working.  I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.  The following code samples are (what I believe are the relevant) excerpts from their respective files.

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"@types/react": "^15.0.28",
"@types/react-dom": "^15.5.0",
"@types/react-router": "^4.0.11",
"react": "^15.6.1",
"react-dom": "^15.6.1",
"react-router": "^4.1.1",
"typescript": "^2.3.4"
},
```

index.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import Bids from './Bids';
import { MemoryRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router';

ReactDOM.render(
  <MemoryRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/bids" component={() => <Bids />} />
      <Route exact path="/" component={() => <App />} />
    </Switch>
  </MemoryRouter>
 ,
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
```

And Bids and App are both react components with simple "hello world" render functions

```
class App extends React.Component<{}, null> {
  render() {
```

The problem that I'm having is that I cannot get my program to render the non-default path.

If I navigate to "http://localhost:3000/" I get the App component.
If I navigate to "http://localhost:3000/bids" I get the App component.
If I navigate to "http://localhost:3000/randomString" I get the App component.

If I switch them in the code (i.e. "/bids" points to App and "/" points to Bids) then I can only see the Bids component on any path.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried putting `/` first, then `/bids`?

Comment: Yes.  Doesn't change the behavior at all.

Comment: Why `MemoryRouter`? From the docs it says that it [does not read or write to the address bar](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/MemoryRouter.md).

Comment: Have you tried using the `react-router-dom` package instead of `react-router`?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the comments (Jesse and Alex) the answer came together.  Switching to react-router-dom and BrowserRouter solved the issue.

```
"@types/react": "^15.0.28",
"@types/react-dom": "^15.5.0",
"@types/react-router-dom": "^4.0.4",
"react": "^15.6.1",
"react-dom": "^15.6.1",
"react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
"typescript": "^2.3.4"
```

and

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import Bids from './Bids';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/bids" component={() => <Bids />} />
      <Route exact path="/" component={() => <App />} />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
 ,
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You most install package react-router-dom

```
yarn add react-router-dom -W

npm i react-router-dom --save
```